# got OR-CBAT-15, want to switch the trial to the right account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

OR-CBAT-15,  I got this when I was activating my account 'A' with my Visa card, I wrongly activated my another account 'B' minutes ago in chrome(my mistake...)
Is there any ways that activate my account 'A' with my Visa card and deactivate my account 'B' ? Since I bought a colab pro+ in account 'A'.

Comment: Your credit card is attached to a "Payments Account". That account is linked to a Billing Account. Attach that billing account to project B and remove it from project A. The Payment and Billing accounts are separate accounts with their own websites for management.

Comment: can not fix the problem. :(

Comment: Not sure if is helpful to know you are not alone https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219092749